# SKlearn's LinearRegression method giving error output

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to learn the following code in colab.

```
x = df.TV
y= df.Sales

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

 LinearRegression(x,y)
```

and getting the following error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ee125dd306e2> in <module>()
----> 1 LinearRegression(x,y)

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: The x and y arguments are not passed to the LinearRegression model directly, but to the fit() method i.e: LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
You can find this in the documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Comment: In addition to the last comment, x should be 2 dimensional. Try `x= df[['TV']]`.

Answer (score 0):

LinearRegression doesn't take training data and target data as arguments. You need to use the fit method to fit the training data to the model.

```
reg = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
```